# Examples of families of graphs where the number of maximal independent sets is greater than a polynomial of the number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am interested in finding some relatively easy families of graphs where the number of maximal independent sets is greater than a polynomial of the number of vertices. Can you provide examples of such families of graphs?

The only example I know of is the complete graph $K_n$, which has $n$ maximal independent sets (each vertex forms a singleton independent set). However, this is an example where the number of maximal independent sets is a polynomial of the number of vertices.

Comment: Please confirm that you are looking for "[maximal independent sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))" instead of "[maximum independent sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))". For the former,  most of graph families with bounded maximum degree would do.

Comment: Yes, I mean maximal independent sets. I'm looking for some concrete easy to prove examples.

Comment: @Apass.Jack If a graph has an exponential number of *maximum* independent sets, then it certainly has an exponential number of *maximal* independent sets.

Comment: @Mike You are right. My concern was whether there are more easy-examples of maximal independent sets. I was investigating a general statement about graphs with bounded degree or bounded treewidth. For maximum independent sets, it is less likely to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forest of $n$ disconnected $K_2$'s has $2n$ vertices and $2^n$ maximal independent sets (MISs).
[image]

For each forest above, we can add an vertex that connects to one vertex of each $K_2$. It becomes a connected graph with $2n+1$ vertices and $2^n+1$ MISs.
[image]

We can replace $K_2$ with any fixed graph of $v$ vertices and $\ell$ MISs. The forest will have $vn$ vertices and $\ell^n$ MISs. The connected version will have $vn+1$ vertices and $\ge\ell^n+1$ MISs.

---

A [square grid graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph#Square_grid_graph) of size $2\times n$ has $2f_n$ MISs, where $f_1=f_2=1$, $f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}$ is the Fibonacci sequence.
[image]

---

More examples can be found in literature. For example, most of the families in the paper [*The Number of Maximum Independent Sets in Graphs*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228931969_The_number_of_maximum_independent_sets_in_graphs) by Min-Jen Jou and Gerard J. Chang are straightforward to understand. For all of them the number of maximal independent sets is exponential w.r.t. to the number of vertices.